# Use jq command to display a two dimensional JSON array

Tags: json, jq

Is there a simple way to display a 2D JSON array using `jq`, so that each subarray is on its own line?

E.g. If I have this JSON:

```
{
  "array": [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9]
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to use `jq` to print out:

```
1 2 3
4 5
6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply  compact `-c` output:

```
$ jq -c '.array[]' test.json 
[1,2,3]
[4,5]
[6,7,8,9]
```

---

Or if you also need to join array values by space char:

```
$ jq -rc '.array[] | join(" ")' test.json 
1 2 3
4 5
6 7 8 9
```